# In R : extract information in text sentence

Tags: r, split, extract, sentence

I have some article's full text. I want to extract some information(like year or month) to analysis it.

And As an example of the structure of article text,

> December 4, 2016 Sunday, LENGTH: (length of main text), HEADLINE: (the
>   title of article), BYLINE: (reporter name), BODY: (main text)

I have this all texts in one line by one article.(So I think it can be possible that treat the article structure as a string.)

In this format, how can I extract the LENGTH, HEADLINE, BYLINE values and make the data frame?

I think It could be possible If use the regular expression properly but I don't know how to exactly.

Comment: Definitely regex, see ?regexpr or [regexpr](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the solution below is helpful. I am sure more efficient ways are possible, check out `gsub`, `grep`, `stringr`.

---

```
DF<-data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, ",", fixed=TRUE)))
DF$X1 <- paste(DF$X1,DF$X2, sep = ",")    
new_df<-as.data.frame(lapply(DF, function(x) gsub(".*:", "", x)))
new_df<-subset(new_df, select = -X2)
colnames(new_df)<-c("Date","Length","Headline","ByLine","Other")
new_df
```

*output*

```
                       Date      Length                                            Headline
1   December 4, 2016 Sunday  1070 words  Korea presents new farm development model globally
2 Noveember 10, 2016 Friday  1070 words  Korea presents new farm development model globally
             ByLine Other
1  By Yoon Ja-young   ~~~
2  By Yoon Ja-young   ~~~
```

---

*data*

```
 x<- c("December 4, 2016 Sunday, LENGTH: 1070 words, HEADLINE: Korea
       presents new farm development model globally, BYLINE: By Yoon Ja-young, BODY: ~~~",
      "Noveember 10, 2016 Friday, LENGTH: 1070 words, HEADLINE: Korea 
       presents new farm development model globally, BYLINE: By Yoon Ja-young, BODY: ~~~")
```

**update:** As mentioned in comments by @G.Grothendieck, changed the solution to display fields as columns.

Answer (score 1):

First define the test data reproducibly -- we used two instances of the data shown in the question.  We note that the tricky part is that each record runs over more than 1 line in the question.

Read in `Lines` -- with the real data replace `textConnection(Lines)`, which is to keep the code self-contained, with `"myfile.txt"`, say.

Then the first `sub` inserts a space at the beginning of each line and the second replaces everything up to and including LENGTH: on any line containing LENGTH: with newline, `DATE:`, the date and `LENGTH:` .  The `gsub` inserts a newline before each keyword, and the `paste` collapses it all into one large newline separated string.  `strsplit`splits it back out again so that the newlines we added are effected.

The data is now in DCF format so we can read it using `read.dcf` .  DCF format separates records by one or more blank lines and starts each field with the fieldname followed by a colon and space followed by the value.  The value can run onto multiple lines provided the subsequent lines are indented, e.g. start with a space.

This gives a matrix with the 5 indicated columns.  The last `sub` removes commas at the end of each element and the last `gsub` replaces newlines with spaces.

Note that we have placed the fields in columns which is normally how one represents data in R but if you really want it in rows then use `t(dcf)`.

```
# test data

Lines <- "December 4, 2016 Sunday, LENGTH: 1070 words, HEADLINE: Korea presents new farm
development model globally, BYLINE: By Yoon Ja-young, BODY: ~~~
December 4, 2016 Sunday, LENGTH: 1070 words, HEADLINE: Korea presents new farm
development model globally, BYLINE: By Yoon Ja-young, BODY: ~~~"

# code

L0 <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
L <- sub("^", " ", L0)
L <- sub("(.*) LENGTH:", "\nDATE: \\1 LENGTH:", L)
L <- gsub("(\\w+:)", "\n\\1", L)
L <- paste(L, collapse = "\n")
L <- unlist(strsplit(L, "\n"))
dcf <- read.dcf(textConnection(L))
dcf[] <- sub(",$", "", dcf)
dcf[] <- gsub("\n", " ", dcf)
```

This gives the following 5 column character matrix:

```
> dcf

     DATE                      LENGTH      
[1,] "December 4, 2016 Sunday" "1070 words"
[2,] "December 4, 2016 Sunday" "1070 words"
     HEADLINE                                             BYLINE            
[1,] "Korea presents new farm development model globally" "By Yoon Ja-young"
[2,] "Korea presents new farm development model globally" "By Yoon Ja-young"
     BODY 
[1,] "~~~"
[2,] "~~~"
```

**Update:** Added date to output.

Comment: Column-wise makes more sense, than rows-wise. nice solution.

Comment: Normally in data processing the fields are columns, not rows.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a start: Use `strsplit` to extract the parts you need. This code is a bit messy but it works:

```
sentence <- "December 4, 2016 Sunday, LENGTH: 1070 words, HEADLINE: Korea presents new farm development model globally, BYLINE: By Yoon Ja-young"

Date <- as.character(sapply(strsplit(sentence, "LENGTH"), "[[",1))
Rows <- as.character(sapply(strsplit(sentence, "LENGTH"), "[[",2))
Length <- gsub(":","", as.character(sapply(strsplit(Rows, ","), "[[",1)))
Headline <- as.character(sapply(strsplit(as.character(sapply(strsplit(Rows, ","), "[[",2)), ":"), "[[",2))
Byline <- as.character(sapply(strsplit(as.character(sapply(strsplit(Rows, ","), "[[",3)), ":"), "[[",2))
```

Then gather the rows in a dataframe:

```
  Df <- data.frame(Date, Length, Headline, Byline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that uses string splitting and a bit of regex all in the base R package. So long as the data are always in the format shown it will work.

```
data <- "December 4, 2016 Sunday, LENGTH: 1070 words, HEADLINE: Korea presents new farm development model globally, BYLINE: By Yoon Ja-young, BODY: ~~~"

textParse <- function(dat){
    tmp <- strsplit(dat, ', ')[[1]]

    time <- as.Date(paste(tmp[1:2], collapse = ' '), format="%B %d %Y")

    len <- strsplit(gsub(".*LENGTH: (\\d+)", "\\1", dat), " ")[[1]][1]

    headline <- paste(strsplit(tmp[4], ' ')[[1]][2:length(strsplit(tmp[4], ' ')[[1]])], collapse = ' ')

    byline <- paste(strsplit(tmp[5], ' ')[[1]][3:length(strsplit(tmp[5], ' ')[[1]])], collapse = ' ')

    body <- paste(strsplit(tmp[6], ' ')[[1]][2:length(strsplit(tmp[6], ' ')[[1]])], collapse = ' ')

    return(as.data.frame(cbind(time, len, headline, byline, body)))
}

textParse(data)
```

Output:

```
 time   len                                            headline     byline
1 17139 1070 Korea presents new farm development model globally Yoon Ja-young
  body
1  ~~~
```

edit: Note that time in R is represented as an integer of "the number of days since 1970-01-01" [R: Date-time Conversion](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html)